# NXT software on Windows 10 isn't detecting NXT brick

Tags: nxt, software

I have the Mindstorms NXT software and brick (CPU), and I worked with them a long time ago running NXT on a Windows XP. Now, I would like to retrieve the brick to teach my son, and I installed the NXT software on Windows 10. The application runs well, but it does not detect the brick. I have read that NXT software is not supported on Windows 10, but other sites tell that NXT works well on Windows 10.
Could someone give me more details on how to install and run the NXT software on Windows 10?

Comment: Hmm, Did you try right-clicking the software, go to the "compatibility" tab and run it in compatibility mode for older Windows models? If this works, let me know and I'll post this as an answer.

Comment: Oh, I forgot that you had to click 'properties' when you right-click. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4):

You need a newer version of the Lego Fantom Driver.

You can download it here as part of the whole software kit:
https://education.lego.com/en-us/downloads/retiredproducts/nxt/software

If you want JUST the driver on it's own, scroll to the advanced section at the bottom of this page:
https://www.lego.com/en-us/themes/mindstorms/downloads

And grab the NXT Fantom Driver file

[image]

Unzip the downloaded file, then follow the usual "install driver from disk" under win 10 procedure.

The driver works perfectly fine under windows 10:

[image]

But some of the driver installers for 64bit have an error in the install script, and need to be patched before they work.  If your driver setup (Assuming you use the exe setup method) fails, the instructions to patch the driver can be found [here](https://mullzk.ch/2014/02/21/installing-lego-mindstorm-nxt-fantom-driver-on-64bit-windows/):

> Your installation will fail if you are using a 64bit-Windows. The reason for this is a slightly defect setup.ini-file, which refers to a LegoMindstormsNXTdriver64Supp.msi which does not exist.
>
> I don’t know when Lego will fix this (current version 1.2.0 still has the problem), but there is an easy workaround:
>
> - Download the File, Unzip it
> - Go to „NXT Fantom Drivers\NXT Fantom Drivers\Windows\1.2\1.2.0, open setup.ini in your favorite editor (still using notepad???)
> - Search for the line „[LegoMindstormsNXTdriver64Supp.msi]“
> - In the next line, enter another, valid path (even if it has nothing to do with the Driver-Support). e.g. change it to   „Path=Products\LEGO_NXT_Driver_64\NXT_D02\LegoMindstormsNXTdriver64.msi“.
> - Save the file
> - Start the normal setup.exe
> - When the installer asks you which components you want do install, deselect the „LEGO MINDSTORMS NXT x64 Driver Support“ LegoInstaller
>
> [image]
>
> - Finish the rest of the installer with the defaults, everything should run smooth now. The Driver-Support files are not necessary for normal use